# Custom Suggestion List on TouchKeyboard

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

is there a way to implement custom suggestions to the touch keyboard when user using a specific application?

As user types in this application, only these custom suggestions (or maybe mixed between the native suggestions from cortana/windows 10 and also the app user is currently using) will be displayed on the touch keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system touch keyboard does not offer extensibility yet, so you can't provide custom suggestions there. You could only implement similar functionality as a "popup" above the entry field the user is currently editing. You could utilize a custom `Flyout` to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will look up to it.